# Is the aboutToQuit() signal of the QCoreApplication still supported in Qt 5.1.0?

Tags: c++, qt

The program starts upon opening a .txt file. Upon exit, I would like it to close the .txt file. Here are the code snippets:

MYRELAYSERVER:

```
void MyRelayServer::exitHandler()
{
    qDebug() << mFileName << " closed!" << mTcpPort;
    if (mDataLog)
        mTextStream << mFileName << " closed!" << mTcpPort;
    mFile.close();

}
```

MAIN:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "myrelayserver.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QObject>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    MyRelayServer server(9999);
    QObject::connect(&a, SIGNAL(aboutToQuit()), &server, SLOT(exitHandler()));
    return a.exec();
}
```

However, it does not execute exitHandler.

[image]
It also does not display any intellisense from the signals of QCoreApplication a.
[image]

Comment: it is in the doc so I guess yes. Don't put too much faith into intellisense.

Comment: But it didnt work.. For one, it didnt print to console that it closed the file. Second, the text file has no content.

Comment: is myrelayserver a subclass of Qobject? show the class

Comment: it is. I used the qt class wizard

Comment: Have the same problem with `aboutToQuit()`. Normal signals work, the ones from QCoreApplication just aren't recognized.
I've looked in the source, they are `protected`, don't know if that influences something.

Comment: @Alan Signals are not `protected` in Qt 5.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue.
Don't know the causes, but changing `a` to a pointer fixed it.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "myrelayserver.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QObject>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication *a = new QCoreApplication (argc, argv);
    MyRelayServer server(9999);
    QObject::connect(a, SIGNAL(aboutToQuit()), &server, SLOT(exitHandler()));
    return a->exec();
}
```

It was available in autocomplete at least (in Qt Creator).

Answer (score 1):

Properly designed classes in C++ implement the RAII concept. `QFile` does it, too. Thus you don't need to worry about closing the file manually. As long as you don't leak the instance of `QFile` object, it will be closed upon destruction.

Why won't you inspect the [`qcoreapplication.h` header](http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qcoreapplication.h.html#179) yourself?